# Custom location for custom Django commands

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I have multiple apps and would like to add custom `Command` which is general (`populate_db`) to all apps. However, Django seems to be registering custom commands only from the `INSTALLED_APPS` locations (i.e. you must place `management` folder within a folder of an app).

Is there a way to place `management` folder in `project_folder`. Here is the desired dir structure:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── app_1
|   ├── admin.py
|   └── ...
├── app_2
|   ├── admin.py
|   └── ...
├── project_folder
|   ├── settings.py
|   └── management
|       ├── __init__.py
|       └── commands
|           ├── __init__.py
|           └── populate_db.py    
└── manage.py
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Django only looks for management commands in `management/commands` for your installed apps. There isn't another way to register them.

In your case, you could add `project_folder` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, and Django should find your management command.

Another common approach is to create an app called `'core'` or `'main'`, which includes utilities which are for the entire project like your `populate_db` management command.